# Oracle left join with Union gives duplicate records

Tags: oracle11g

Have two tables payment, payment_info , trying with left join and union to get the ordnums, it gives me duplicate records, below is my tables data structure.

Payment Table:

| id | invoice | cardpay | gpay | phonepe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4567 | 0000123 | null | null |
| 2 | 4567 | null | dummy@dummy | null |
| 3 | 4567 | null | null | P@dummy |
| 4 | 4568 | 0000124 | null | null |

Payment_info Table:

| ordnum | payment_method | payment_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | C | 0000123 |
| 102 | G | dummy@dummy |
| 103 | C | 0000124 |

Query:

```
select pinfo.ordnum from 
payment p
left join payment_info pinfo
on (select payment_info.ordnum
from payment_info
where payment_info.payment_method = 'C'
and payment_info.payment_value = p.cardpay
union 
select payment_info.ordnum
from payment_info  
where payment_info.payment_method = 'G'
and payment_info.payment_value = p.gpay 
union
 select payment_info.ordnum
from payment_info
where payment_info.payment_method = 'P'
and payment_info.payment_value = p.phonepe ) = pinfo.ordnum
where p.invoice = '4567'
```

Result: It gives 3 duplicate records.

| ordnum |
| --- |
| 101 |
| 101 |
| 101 |

Expected result value is : 101,102, null

Can you please explain me on why it is generating duplicate records, also please let me know how can I solve this, it works good with "OR", but that would cause performance issue, any other solution that that would be really helpful.

Also in sql server it works good.

Answer (score 0):

How about something simpler?

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  payment (id, invoice, cardpay, gpay, phonepe) as
  3    (select 1, 4567, '0000123', null         , null      from dual union all
  4     select 2, 4567, null     , 'dummy@dummy', null      from dual union all
  5     select 3, 4567, null     , null         , 'P@dummy' from dual union all
  6     select 4, 4568, '0000124', null         , null      from dual
  7    ),
  8  payment_info (ordnum, payment_method, payment_value) as
  9    (select 101, 'C', '0000123'     from dual union all
 10     select 102, 'G', 'dummy@dummy' from dual union all
 11     select 103, 'C', '0000124'     from dual
 12    )
```

Query begins here: outer join it is, but simplified as `coalesce` returns the first non-null value. This should be OK because there can be only one payment "method" (cardpay, gpay or phonepe) per `ID`.

```
 13  select p.id, i.ordnum
 14  from payment p left join payment_info i on
 15    coalesce(p.cardpay, p.gpay, p.phonepe) = i.payment_value
 16  where p.invoice = 4567;

        ID     ORDNUM
---------- ----------
         1        101
         2        102
         3

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT i.ordnum
FROM   payment p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN payment_info i
       ON ( (i.payment_method, i.payment_value) IN (
              ('C', p.cardpay),
              ('G', p.gpay),
              ('P', p.phonepe)
            ) )
WHERE  p.invoice = 4567;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT i.ordnum
FROM   payment p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN payment_info i
       ON (  (i.payment_method = 'C' AND i.payment_value = p.cardpay)
          OR (i.payment_method = 'G' AND i.payment_value = p.gpay)
          OR (i.payment_method = 'P' AND i.payment_value = p.phonepe)
          )
WHERE  p.invoice = 4567;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE payment (id, invoice, cardpay, gpay, phonepe) AS
  SELECT 1, 4567, '0000123', NULL         , NULL      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4567, NULL     , 'dummy@dummy', NULL      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 4567, NULL     , NULL         , 'P@dummy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 4568, '0000124', NULL         , NULL      FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE payment_info (ordnum, payment_method, payment_value) AS
  SELECT 101, 'C', '0000123'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 102, 'G', 'dummy@dummy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 103, 'C', '0000124'     FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ORDNUM |
| --- |
| 101 |
| 102 |
| *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7l1ccJPq)

Comment: MT0 , still left outer join "IN" operator uses "OR" internally , think it will create performance impact , do you see otherwise

Comment: @user3387870 There will be a negligible performance impact using `OR` compared to using `UNION` and multiple self-joins (both of which come with large overheads of extra I/O and sorting and filtering). If you are worried about it then you should profile the code on your tables.